# Python remove an item from a random list, after being picked

Tags: python, random

How would I go about allowing a random.choice to pick an item from a list(once, twice, or three times) and then be removed from the list.

for example it could be 1-10 and the after the number 1 gets picked, no longer allow 1 to be picked until the program is reset

This is a made up example with colors and numbers replacing my words

```
colors = ["red","blue","orange","green"]
numbers = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
designs = ["stripes","dots","plaid"]

random.choice (colors)
if colors == "red":
    print ("red")
    random.choice (numbers)
    if numbers == "2":##Right here is where I want an item temporarily removed(stripes for example)
        random.choice (design)
```

I hope that helps, I'm trying to keep my actual project a secret =\ sorry for the inconvenience

Forgot to mention in the code, after red gets picked that needs to be removed as well

Comment: Well, how *would* you go about it? Personally, I'd probably skip `random.choice`, and instead `shuffle` the list and then `pop` the last item off it, but *show us what you have tried*.

Comment: Maybe just keep track of the items you've chosen so far, and don't pick from there.

The problem is that given large sets from which you've already chosen a large proportion of the items, it could a while to find an item that hasn't been chosen yet, using random numbers.

Comment: Popping the item off the list would only allow each item to be picked once correct? I'm looking for something like the number one could be drawn 3 times and then removed as not to be picked again

Comment: @user2795843 check out my modified answer

Answer (score 4):

You can use `random.choice` and `list.remove`

```
from random import choice as rchoice

mylist = range(10)
while mylist:
    choice = rchoice(mylist)
    mylist.remove(choice)
    print choice
```

Or, as `@Henry Keiter` said, you can use `random.shuffle`

```
from random import shuffle

mylist = range(10)
shuffle(mylist)
while mylist:
    print mylist.pop()
```

If you still need your **shuffled** list after that, you can do as follows:

```
...
shuffle(mylist)
mylist2 = mylist
while mylist2:
    print mylist2.pop()
```

And now you will get an empty list **mylist2**, and your shuffled list **mylist**.

**EDIT**
About code you posted. You are writing `random.choice(colors)`, but what `random.choice` does? It choices random answer and **returns**(!) it. So you have to write

```
chosen_color = random.choice(colors)
if chosen_color == "red":
    print "The color is red!"
    colors.remove("red") ##Remove string from the list
    chosen_number = random.choice(numbers)
    if chosen_number == "2":
        chosen_design = random.choice(design)
```

Comment: It's sufficient to `shuffle` the list once, then keep popping... no need to keep shuffling it... You also don't need to check the length, just that it's truthy... `shuffle(mylist); while(mylist): print mylist.pop()` will be enough

Comment: oops - don't need the `()` around the `while (mylist)` either... sorry - was copying your example too closely :)

Comment: Ooh, yeah. Sometimes I forget about the `()` too :)

Comment: Bit of a newbie to python here, what exactly does while do?

Comment: @user2795843, check out the following pages: [WhileLoop - Python Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop), [7. Compound statements — Python v2.7.5 documentationn](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#while)

Comment: so then Would the while command be useful for temporarily removing an item from a list? Remove "string1" until later without having to re type it

Comment: Thank for your help so far i feel like i'm nearly there. Now is red removed permanently until i restart the program? or can it be called later down the road if requested.

Comment: Actually, yes. When you remove `'red'` from the list, you 'lose' it, until you create it again (`mylist.append("red")`), or until you restart the program. If you want your list to hold all the variables, but make them not to be selected twice, you can make a copy of `mylist`: `mylist_copy = mylist`, before removing stuff from `mylist`